2020 VW Jetta SEL air distribution map
the issue I have is that my ac on my 2 right dash vents emit hot air when I have it on low, but my 2 left dash vents come out cool. Could something be blocked? I changed air filters and everything

Welcome To Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does your car have dual-zone climate control? (Separate control of driver and passenger side?)

Yes I do have dual zone climate

So it might be expected to have different temperature air from the vents. Are the two zones synchronized? What I am getting at: is it an operator error?

Yes, the two zones are synchronized. The passenger vents never get cold air to come out,

More than likely a blend door actuator which affects the vents you're talking about has died. The blend door actuator is a motor which turns the flap and directs air from either the hot side (heater core) or the cool side (a/c evaporator). Most are fairly much a PITB to get to, but can be done by a DIYer if you know where to find it. You can also test them by applying 12v power directly to the correct pins on the unit. It should look like this:


I love you Paul, no Diddy. Do you know where it could possibly be located at? And by correct unit you mean the fuses right?

@FranciscoLuna - No, I mean directly to the actuator itself. I don't know which pins would cause the motor to run, but usually there is one ground and two power. Power is applied to each pin individually to move the motor either forward or back.

@FranciscoLuna - Here's an explanation of the blend door and here's a how-to on how to replace the motor in your Jetta. Mind you, I haven't looked at either video. If you do not find those helpful, there should be some more and can be found by putting your vehicle information into the YouTube search engine along with "blend door actuator replacement" (or you could try location).
